# PHP - Crear un array dinamico a base de ciclos

Tags: php, array

Me encuentro con un gran problema, quiero agregar dentro de un array, mas array a partir de ciclos, pero no encuentro una solucion, mi codigo es este:

```
$arrayDetalle = Array();
for($i = 0; $i < $this->contArticulos; $i++){
    $arrayDetalle = array(
        "Nombre"        => $this->nombreVFI[$i],
        "Cantidad"      => $this->cantidadVFI[$i],
        "Subtotal"      => $this->costo_subtotalVFI[$i],
        "Total"         => $this->costo_subtotalVFI[$i] + $this->costo_impuestoVFI[$i],
        "Codigo"        => $this->codigoVFI[$i],
        "Impuestos"     => array(
            "Impuesto"      => $this->impuestoVFI[$i],
            "Porcentaje"    => $this->valor_impuestoVFI[$i],
            "TotalImp"      => $this->costo_impuestoVFI[$i]
        )
    );
}
```

Y luego necesito convertir ese array en un json y mostrarlo en pantalla, sin embargo cuando lo imprimo no aparece nada en pantalla:

```
$json = json_enconde($arrayDetalle);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás sobreescribiendo la variable, quedaría así:

```
$arrayDetalle = Array();
for($i = 0; $i < $this->contArticulos; $i++){
    $arrayDetalle[] = array(  #Aquí está la respuesta, usa [] luego del nombre del array.
        "Nombre"        => $this->nombreVFI[$i],
        "Cantidad"      => $this->cantidadVFI[$i],
        "Subtotal"      => $this->costo_subtotalVFI[$i],
        "Total"         => $this->costo_subtotalVFI[$i] + $this->costo_impuestoVFI[$i],
        "Codigo"        => $this->codigoVFI[$i],
        "Impuestos"     => array(
            "Impuesto"      => $this->impuestoVFI[$i],
            "Porcentaje"    => $this->valor_impuestoVFI[$i],
            "TotalImp"      => $this->costo_impuestoVFI[$i]
        )
    );
}
```

Con esto indicas que se va a agregar otro elemento al `$arrayDetalle[] = ..`

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero ahora tengo otro problema, ese array debo transformarlo a json, y cuando uso la funcion json_encode de php y le paso el array, lo imprimo en pantalla y no me sale nada.

Comment: pues modífica tu pregunta y pon como lo estás haciendo para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Para mostrar información de `json_encode` debes usar echo @DavidEspinal

Comment: ya hice un echo @MáximaAlekz pero no aparece nada y si hago un var_dump me muestra toda la informacion del array

Answer (score 1):

Está mal escrito el nombre de la función:

```
$json = json_enconde($arrayDetalle);
```

Debería ser `json_encode`!

Comment: Si, aqui lo escribi mal pero en el codigo esta bien escrito.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ésto funcionará...

```
$arrayDetalle   = array();
$arrayImpuestos = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $this->contArticulos; $i++ ) {

    $arrayImpuestos[ "Impuesto" ]   = $this->impuestoVFI[ $i ];
    $arrayImpuestos[ "Porcentaje" ] = $this->valor_impuestoVFI[ $i ];
    $arrayImpuestos[ "TotalImp" ]   = $this->costo_impuestoVFI[ $i ];

    $arrayDetalle[ "Nombre" ]    = $this->nombreVFI[ $i ];
    $arrayDetalle[ "Cantidad" ]  = $this->cantidadVFI[ $i ];
    $arrayDetalle[ "Subtotal" ]  = $this->costo_subtotalVFI[ $i ];
    $arrayDetalle[ "Total" ]     = ($this->costo_subtotalVFI[ $i ] + $this->costo_impuestoVFI[ $i ]);
    $arrayDetalle[ "Codigo" ]    = $this->codigoVFI[ $i ];
    $arrayDetalle[ "Impuestos" ] = $arrayImpuestos;
}
```

Comment: hay un pequeñito error de sintaxis, por allí en las asignaciones de `$arrayDetalle`...

Comment: @CJ Nimes no lo veo, es lo que tiene escribir un código al vuelo. No puedo probarlo sin el resto del código o pasar un buen rato escribiendo mokups

Comment: En estas asignaciones `$arrayDetalle = [ "Nombre" ] = ...` sobra el `=` entre la variable y el primer corchete ^^

Comment: @CJ Nimes Cosas que se come un editor y uno no ve hasta que no ejecuta el script. !Corregido!